# Can't find sgfplib.dll

Tags: c#-7.0

I trying to capture fingerprint via my C# code. I have referenced the secugen FDx Pro SDK for windows version 2.3.3.0 and have installed the drivers. Though  I can not see the sgfplib.dll among the other dll files.

when I run the code trying to initialize the SGFingerPrintManager which uses sgfplib.dll, it complains that "sgfplib.dll can not be found" I have read the previous suggestion on this platform, but none solved the problems.

Please I appreciate in advance any suggestion to solve this problem sonnest.

Thanks in advance.

a) I have downloaded FDx Pro SDK for windows and the secugen drivers version 6.7 (64).
b) Also, I tried to copying the sgfplid.dll to the bin folder of my project but problem persists.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LuggageTrackingAndBillingSystem.models;
using SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.Windows;
namespace LuggageTrackingAndBillingSystem
{
    public partial class TsetForSecugen : Form
    {
        Int32 image_width = 200;
        Int32 image_height = 300;
        Int32 image_dpi = 500;

        public TsetForSecugen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeDedive();

        }
        private SGFingerPrintManager m_FPM;

        SGFPMDeviceName device_name = SGFPMDeviceName.DEV_FDU03;

        private void InitializeDedive()
        {
            //Step 1
            if (RuntimePolicyHelper.LegacyV2RuntimeEnabledSuccessfully)
            {
                // This will load a CLR 2 mixed mode assembly
                  m_FPM = new SGFingerPrintManager();
            }

            var err = m_FPM.InitEx(image_width, image_height, image_dpi);
        }
        private void DrawImage(Byte[] imgData, PictureBox picBox)
        {
            int colorval;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image_width, image_height);
            picBox.Image = (Image)bmp;

            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
                {
                    colorval = (int)imgData[(j * image_width) + i];
                    bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(colorval, colorval, colorval));
                }
            }
            picBox.Refresh();
        }

        private void GetImage()
        {
          //Capturing Finger Image Step 3
            Byte[] fp_image = new Byte[image_width * image_height];
            Int32 iError;
            iError = m_FPM.GetImage(fp_image);
            if (iError == (Int32)SGFPMError.ERROR_NONE)
            {
                DrawImage(fp_image, pictureBox1);
            }
        }

        private void TsetForSecugen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeDedive();


            GetDevieInfo();




        }
        private void GetDevieInfo()
        {
            #region Det Device Info step 2
            //Get Device info
            SGFPMDeviceInfoParam pInfo = new SGFPMDeviceInfoParam();
            pInfo = new SGFPMDeviceInfoParam();
            Int32 iError = m_FPM.GetDeviceInfo(pInfo);
            if (iError == (Int32)SGFPMError.ERROR_NONE)
            {
                image_width = pInfo.ImageWidth;
                image_height = pInfo.ImageHeight;
            }
            #endregion
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Actual result:The expected result is to be able to capture fingerpring

Error Meaage: Header[FDx SDK Pro.NET]  . Body[can't find sgfplib.dll]

Comment: [This page](https://secugen.com/products/sdk/) mentions C# sample code. Have you looked into it?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by gotten the executable file of  FDx SDK Pro for windows and installed.

The problem is caused by the  FDx SDK Pro For windows not being able to see the sgfplib.dll file which is automatically installed in windows/System32 and Windows/sysWOW64 directories during installation.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Sorry, i know this post was over 3 years. But now, I also meet this error.
When i download from segen page, I can find executable file of FDx SDK Pro for windows in folder. 
So, can you share to me more information about this ?