# Can not find sgfplib.dd

Tags: c#-8.0

I am developing a Wpf application and use secugen device.
When I add secugen code into application and run.
It shows error:

> Error : Can not find sgfplib.dd

I also read this post of KenTechO but I can not find the executable file of FDx SDK Pro for windows in folder after downloading.

[Can't find sgfplib.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57857024/cant-find-sgfplib-dll)

I tried copy & paste file sgfplib.dd in both System32 & SysWOW64. It still gets error.

I also restart pc many times.

Please I appreciate in advance any suggestion to solve this problem sonnest.

Thanks in advance.